# Different types allowed while linking

Tags: c, linker

I have two files. The first `a.c` has

```
extern int i;
int main()
{
    i = 5;
    printf("i=%d",i);
}
```

the other file `b.c` has

```
struct i
{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

when compile these two files and link them, I get `i=5`as output.

Why is this happening? `i` has seprate types in `a.c` and `b.c`.

Comment: The file [b.c] doesn't affect anything (except that it won't compile as given here): there is no object called `i` there. An answer to your question **depends on the programming language**. Please do choose either C or C++. State which compiler you're using and the invocation command you're using.

Comment: We can only guess that the compiler optimizes `i=5; printf("i=%d",i);` as `printf("i=%d",5)` and removes the unneded `i`.

Comment: Note: there is a semicolon missing after the struct definition.

Answer (score 1):

In C, different occurrences of the same identifier may have different
types in the same *compilation* unit (never mind linkage). This
program is fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct i
{
    int i;
};

static int i;

int main(void)
{
    i = 1;
    struct i ii;
    ii.i = i;
    printf("%d\n",ii.i);
    return 0;
}
```

Structure tags and variable names are in different namespaces, per C99
Standard:

**6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers**

> If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a
>   translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities.
>   Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> — label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
>
> — the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any
>   of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
>
> — the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name
>   space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the
>   member via the . or -> operator);
>
> — all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as
>   enumeration constants).

(The program is also legal C++, swapping `<stdio.h>` for `<cstdio>`)

Answer (score 0):

Since i is declared in a.c that is what will happen, the declaration in "b.c" cannot remove something in the a.c file especially since you don't declare any variable of type i.